# Firebird 2.1 - Simple SELECT

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.1

I would like to union some data, but a simple select example not working. Selecting existing tables work fine...

```
SELECT 1 as foo
```

Message:

```
can't format message 13:896 -- message file C:\xxxx\firebird.msg not found.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
corrupt pool.
```

In MySQL and Postgres is no problem with these simple select..

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 12):

Firebird (like many other DBMS) requires a `FROM` clause. In Oracle you'd use the `DUAL` table, in Firebird you can use `RDB$DATABASE`

```
SELECT 1 as foo
FROM RDB$DATABASE;
```

As `RDB$DATABASE` always contains exactly one row, this works the same way as Oracle's `DUAL` table (or IBM's `SYSDUMMY`)

Comment: Is there no "normal" way to simple select...? Maybe "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as now" or else?

Comment: @Rookee: no, there is no other way (that *is* the "normal" way). A `SELECT` statement **always** requires a `FROM` clause (this complies with the SQL standard)

Answer (score 3):

It incorrect syntax for firebird. Right `SELECT 1 as foo from RDB$DATABASE`. `RDB$DATABASE` it system table for it RDBMS. You can read about FIREBIRD system tables [here](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.SystemObjects).